# VBA Macro: Copying worksheets from one Excel file to another

Tags: vba, excel

I need help on copying worksheets from one excel workbook to another. Currently, this is my code but it does not run:

```
Sub Code()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\w1.xlsm"
Sheets (Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
Copy after:=Workbooks("w2.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Workbooks("Client Info Template.xlsm").Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yeah that's kind of hinted at already by OP saying "it does not run".

Comment: @TylerH fair enough, and obvious enough to hopefully most of us, but "it does not run" isn't really a clear/unambiguous problem statement whereas "I get a compile error" removes all uncertainty.

Comment: @Zeta the basic code you need for this solution can be produced from the Macro Recorder if you simply perform the actions and record the macro. Please try that, and it can be modified if needed.

Comment: @DavidZemens I agree the question is too broad and needs more detail, but that's a separate matter best handled by close voting (not answering...)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Sheets...` and `Copy ...` as two lines, try a single line:

`Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy After:=Workbooks("w2.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

This probably still won't work, or at least not reliably, because `Sheets.Count` may exceed the count of sheets in the destination workbook, so it is better to fully qualify all of your objects:

```
Sub Code()

Dim w1 as Workbook, w2 as Workbook
Set w1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\w1.xlsm")
Set w2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\w2.xlsm")  '## Modify as needed

w1.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy After:=w2.Sheets(w2.Sheets.Count)

End Sub
```